# register_sidebar function problem

Tags: register-sidebar

What's wrong in this function?

```
function init(){
    //go through each sidebar and register it
    $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();


    if(is_array($sidebars)){
        foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
            $sidebar_class = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($sidebar);
            register_sidebar(array(
                'name'=>$sidebar,
                'id' => 'new-sidebars',
                'before_widget' => '<div class="sb_widget">',
                'after_widget' => '</div>',
                'before_title' => '<h4>',
                'after_title' => '</h4>',
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

here is the log:

Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the arguments array for the "Sidebar" sidebar. Defaulting to "sidebar-1". Manually set the id to "sidebar-1" to silence this notice and keep existing sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.) in /home/incentiv/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4147

Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the arguments array for the "Footer" sidebar. Defaulting to "sidebar-2". Manually set the id to "sidebar-2" to silence this notice and keep existing sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.) in /home/incentiv/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4147

Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the arguments array for the "Contact Top" sidebar. Defaulting to "sidebar-3". Manually set the id to "sidebar-3" to silence this notice and keep existing sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.) in /home/incentiv/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4147

Comment: here is the log:

Comment: The ID should be unique, it looks like you are trying to register multiple sidebars to the same ID.

Comment: So I need to copy the all function and change only the ID?

Comment: What are you looping over? Can you var_dump/print_r that and add it to your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how to done it?

Comment: `print_r( $sidebars);` right after `$sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars(); `

Comment: Thank you. here is the print:
Array ( [About] => About [Products] => Products [Solutions] => Solutions [null] => null [Industries] => Industries [Services] => Services [consulting] => consulting [Partners] => Partners )

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, you haven't provide any id to your sidebar which cause problem to generate unique id for each sidebar from above code. So, will you replace your code with these lines. Hope, this will hep to figure our your problem. You can found a good [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12318/sidebar-generator) for similar to your problem. (updated)

```
public static function init(){
        //go through each sidebar and register it
        $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
        //$sidebars = $this->get_sidebars();
        if(is_array($sidebars)){
            foreach($sidebars as $key => $sidebar){
                $sidebar_class = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($sidebar);
                register_sidebar(array(
                                        'id' => $key,
                    'name'=>$sidebar,
                    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                    'after_widget' => '</div>',
                    'before_title' => '<h4 class="sb_title">',
                    'after_title' => '</h4>',
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do I need to replace the all function init() or just the if loop?

Comment: Just replace your register-sidebar  with my code and see, if it works for you..

Comment: I change it and to:
`function init(){
  //go through each sidebar and register it
     $sidebars = sidebar_generator::get_sidebars();
     

     if(is_array($sidebars)){
   foreach($sidebars as $sidebar){
    $sidebar_class = sidebar_generator::name_to_class($sidebar);
    register_sidebar(array(
                'name'=>$sidebar,
'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget sb_widget '.$sidebar_class.' %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h4 class="sb_title">',
'after_title' => '</h4>',
));
   }
  }
 }
`

Comment: Here is the log sample:
Strict Standards: Non-static method sidebar_generator::name_to_class() should not be called statically in /home/incentiv/public_html/wp-content/themes/ExposeFolio/includes/m_s/multiple_sidebars.php on line 57

Comment: For not static method you need to initialize it like so:

$var = new ClassName();
$var->method();

Comment: can you kindly write me example for that. I'm not familiar with this syntax

Comment: Will you make your init function static like as: public static function init()

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
Now after I change the function to static I have this log about this new function
`function admin_print_scripts(){
        wp_print_scripts( array( 'sack' ));
        ?>
            
                function add_sidebar( sidebar_name )
                {

```
                var mysack = new sack("<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" );    

                mysack.execute = 1;
                mysack.method = 'POST';
                mysack.setVar( "action", "add_sidebar" );
                mysack.setVar( "sidebar_name", sidebar_name );
                mysack.encVar( "cookie", document.cookie, false );
                mysack.onError = function() { alert('Ajax error. Cannot add sidebar' )};
                mysack.runAJAX();
                return true;
            }

            function remove_sidebar( sidebar_name,num )
            {

                var mysack = new sack("<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" );    

                mysack.execute = 1;
                mysack.method = 'POST';
                mysack.setVar( "action", "remove_sidebar" );
                mysack.setVar( "sidebar_name", sidebar_name );
                mysack.setVar( "row_number", num );
                mysack.encVar( "cookie", document.cookie, false );
                mysack.onError = function() { alert('Ajax error. Cannot add sidebar' )};
                mysack.runAJAX();
                //alert('hi!:::'+sidebar_name);
                return true;
            }
        </script>
    <?php
}`
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: rd_preset_c in /home/incentiv/public_html/wp-content/themes/ExposeFolio/functions/theme-functions.php on line 103